# Reading tweets to my Android App with twitter API - force closes

Tags: android, android-activity, twitter

I am a beginner to Android App Development. I am trying to read tweets to my android app. Using TwitterAsyncTask (learning all of this from a book). But the app force closes after I launch it. What is it I am doing wrong? And how can I know what errors causing force close?

```
package com.balani.fetchtweets;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private TwitterAsyncTask twitterFetcher;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
ListAdapter adapter = new TwitterJSONAdapter();
setListAdapter(adapter);
twitterFetcher = new TwitterAsyncTask();
twitterFetcher.execute("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=abhibalani&count=20");
}

private class TwitterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray>{
private final URI URL = null;

@Override
   protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
   String response = getURLContents(params[0]);
        try {
            return new JSONArray(response);
        } catch (JSONException ex) { return null; }
    }


private String getURLContents(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String xml = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(string);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray response){
if(response == null)
return;
try{
((TwitterJSONAdapter)getListAdapter())
.setData(response);
getListView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
View loading = findViewById(R.id.loading_text);
if(loading!=null)
loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}catch(Exception e){
Log.e("TwitterFeed","Failed to set Adapter");
}
}
}





private class TwitterJSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    JSONArray data;
    //Must be called on the main thread
    private void setData(JSONArray data){
    this.data = data;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    if(data==null)
    return 0;
    else
    return data.length();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(data==null)
            return null;
            try{
            JSONObject element = (JSONObject)data.get(position);
            return element;
            }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
            }
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JSONObject node = (JSONObject)getItem(position);
        ViewGroup listView = null;
        //Reduce, Reuse, Recycle!
        if(convertView == null)
        listView =
        (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate
        (R.layout.twitter_list_item, null);
        else
        listView = (ViewGroup)convertView;
        try{
        boolean retweeted = node.getInt("retweet_count") > 0;
        TextView tv =(TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.text_one);
        tv.setText(node.getString("text"));
        if(retweeted)
        tv.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
        else
        tv.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        tv = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.text_two);
        tv.setText(node.getString("created_at"));

        if(retweeted)
            tv.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
            else
            tv.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("TwitterView","Failed to set list item",e);
                }
                return listView;
        }

    }
}
```

> 07-15 23:24:22.708: I/dalvikvm(30861): DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;. (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V from Landroid/content/res/XResources$XTypedArray;)
>   07-15 23:24:22.708: I/dalvikvm(30861): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray., referenced from method android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.
>   07-15 23:24:22.708: W/dalvikvm(30861): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 82: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;. (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V
>   07-15 23:24:22.708: D/dalvikvm(30861): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0002
>   07-15 23:24:22.978: I/Adreno-EGL(30861): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
>   07-15 23:24:23.008: D/OpenGLRenderer(30861): Enabling debug mode 0
>   07-15 23:24:23.008: W/dalvikvm(30861): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415dfc68)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861): Process: com.balani.fetchtweets, PID: 30861
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at com.balani.fetchtweets.MainActivity$TwitterAsyncTask.getURLContents(MainActivity.java:71)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at com.balani.fetchtweets.MainActivity$TwitterAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at com.balani.fetchtweets.MainActivity$TwitterAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    ... 4 more
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    ... 18 more
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>   07-15 23:24:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(30861):    ... 21 more
>   07-15 23:24:25.128: I/Process(30861): Sending signal. PID: 30861 SIG: 9

Comment: post logcat exception also.

Comment: I hope this is what you were talking about.

Comment: Yes,see below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

Add the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the **application tag** in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it solved the force closed problem. But the tweets doesnt appear. :(

Comment: @Abhi I am not familiar with twitter api,so post your problem with new question.

Comment: Also I dont understand why my question is voted down. I searched but this question wasn't there already so I posted. Is this how guys here demotivate new users and new learners?